# How to re-run animation after animation finishes (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

What I am trying to do is to animate an image across the page, continuously, while being draggable at the same time. Currently, it moves across, is draggable, and goes back to the initial position after the initial animation is done.

However, I don't know how to get it to run again so that it's a continuous loop of animation. I was thinking to put the function animateCloud() inside animateCloud() but not sure where to attach it. Below is the jsFiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/iamacatperson/SfFgt/2/

I would also appreciate if there's a better method of doing this. I am just starting to learn jQuery and I only know a couple of syntax.

Comment: Very similar functionality.. [check this out](http://www.irengba.com/codewell/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why are you using `.stop()` but I guess this should work-

```
function animateCloud() {
    $(cloud).animate({
        left: '300px'
    }, 25000, function() {
        $(this).css({ left: '0' });
         animateCloud();
    });

}
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: works like a charm. It should be possible to avoid recursion (simply to avoid filling the stack), but I guess the memory footprint is minimal.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks! Don't know exactly why I initially put stop(). I guess I was playing around and I thought I needed it.

Comment: Now, I remember, I wanted the animation to stop on mouseover then continue moving on mouseout.

Comment: well you did another mistake. You put callback function in `.css()` and inside it you put `animateCloud()` which according to jQuery Spec is Invalid. Callback functions are functions which are invoked when a particular action is completed hence there is callback in `.animate` etc. In `.css()` you are either assigning or retrieving there is nothing like completion. In technical terms `.css()` is synchronous and functions like `.animate()` are asynchronous. As `.css` does not have callback in your case `animateCloud` was never called again.

Comment: @dewbot: Ok, I'll take note of that. ;)