# How do I loop an animation in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which will animate a div within a slideshow I am creating. The problem is that I can't work out a good way to loop the animation. I have tried various solutions for similar problems here on stackoverflow but none have worked thus far.

My simple code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $s1 = $('#slide1');
    $s1.animate({
        top: "100px"
    }, 1000).delay(5000).slideUp(1000).delay(1000);
});
```

My question is how can I get this animation to loop again from the beginning?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle of the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop .animate JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401535/how-to-loop-animate-jquery)

Comment: @Tushar here it is: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrqe5wtq/).

Comment: @Regent Not just `JS`, `HTML` code also

Comment: @Tushar I actually created this fiddle for two reasons: 1. You asked for _create jsfiddle of the same_. 2. In the first place, HTML has to be in question (to have MCV example in question), not in fiddle (which is another site), and we should encourage people to post HTML in question, not only in _full example fiddle_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this entirely by using CSS. Fiddle attached

https://jsfiddle.net/j6Lqgv9a/

```
#slide1{
position: relative;
    animation: slideIn 10s;
    -moz-animation: slideIn 10s;
    -webkit-animation: slideIn 10s;
    -o-animation: slideIn 10s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes slideIn{
    0%{top:0px;}
    10%{top:100px;}
    50%{top:100px;}
    60%{top:0px;}
}
```

Comment: I do have CSS animations elsewhere in the page but wanted to do this with javascript as more of a learning exercise. However, your answer does appear to be the most efficient and simplest way to achieve the desired effect so I chose your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your animation in a function and re-call that function when animation is complete..

You can find example at [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271112/how-to-re-run-animation-after-animation-finishes-jquery)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the setInterval method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $s1 = $('#slide1');
    $s1.animate({
        top: "100px"
    }, 1000).delay(5000).slideUp(1000).slideDown(1000);
    setInterval(function(){$s1.animate({
        top: "100px"
    }, 1000).slideUp(1000).slideDown(1000); }, 3000);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ooLv58xe/

Comment: This looks like what I need.  Is it possible to use set interval by itself without the above animation?

Comment: Yes you can. But the animation will start after 3 seconds